# Nginx fails to parse config because of scgi_params

Tags: nginx, web-server

I'm trying to install libtorrent, rtorrent and rutorrent. I'm at the stage of installing rutorrent, and their wiki says I have to put this location block in my config file:

```
location /RPC2 {
    include scgi_params;
    scgi_pass unix:/tmp/rpc.sock;
}
```

This is my entire config block for this server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log /home/whitey/sites/localhost/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/whitey/sites/localhost/logs/error.log;
    root /home/whitey/sites/localhost/htdocs;
    index index.html index.php /index.php;

    location / { 

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/phpfpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    location /RPC2 {
        include scgi_params;
        scgi_pass unix:/tmp/rpc.sock;
    }
}
```

When I rebooted nginx for the new config to take effect, I got this error:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "scgi_pass" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/localhost.conf:24
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Now, the SCGI module for nginx has been built by default since version 0.8.42, this is the output from `nginx -v`: `nginx version: nginx/1.1.19`

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `find /etc/nginx/ -name scgi_params`?

Comment: gives me `/etc/nginx/scgi_params`

Comment: Which distro are you running? How did you install Nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your above config is put into `/etc/nginx/conf.d/localhost.conf` and `scgi_params` located at `/etc/nginx`, therefore Nginx cannot find out the included file.

Using absolute path instead:

```
location /RPC2 {
    include /etc/nginx/scgi_params;
    scgi_pass unix:/tmp/rpc.sock;
}
```

Comment: Getting there, but now I get a new error: `unknown directive "scgi_param" in /etc/nginx/scgi_params:1` Here's the entire `scgi_params` file: http://pastebin.com/ExD1fH3e

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

for me it was that my nginx (~0.7 in squeeze) doesnt come with SCGI module

but there is a nginx-full package in backports that does !

i installed it, and now it starts up fine

http://wiki.debian.org/Nginx

http://backports-master.debian.org/Instructions/